# Why does this limit not exist

Tags: calculus

Consider this limit: $$\lim _{x\to 4^+}\sqrt{16-x^2}$$

I had to graph this limit function and the values for $f(4)$ and $f(-4)$ were both equal to $0$, but why does the limit not exist?

Comment: Welcome to MSE please refer to the MathJax tutorial for formatting http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Are you working in $\Bbb C$ or $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Try to calculate for example $\sqrt{16-(4.01)^2}$. You will see that you need to calculate $\sqrt{-0.0801}$ which is not defined on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Because the function doesn't exist for $x>4$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Suppose $x$ was approaching 4 from the right, i.e., $x=4.0000001$ or something.

$x^2=4.0000001^2 > 4.00000000^2 = 16,$ so taking $\sqrt{16-4.0000001^2}$ is effectively taking the square root of a negative number, which is not defined in $\mathbb{R}$.